Search a list of contacts (multiple "OR" clause for name)
I would easily search for contacts whose name is e.g. 'John' or 'Michael' or 'Kevin', etc.
I could use SearchBuilder, but it is very tedious to set filters each time. Or create a similar extension as https://github.com/bhahumanists/bha.searchbuilder...
With FormBuilder I don't know if you can create a 'repeated' filter for the contact.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

I solved this with a trick creating a search form with FormBuilder and adding filter on field "Display Name" with operator ‘Matches Patterns’.
So users can use the | character between names to search multiple contacts.


Have you tried SearchKit? It's pretty easy to an "Or" group.

In SearchKit in the filter conditions I should set the filter based on a parameter of the FormBuilder Filter...I do not know how to do this.  Or is there another method?

It sounds like you don't just want to use SearchKit by itself but you want to build a search form, is that correct?

yes, it is correct

I was thinking of a single input filter where you could use with the syntax ‘,,etc.’
